# MySQL percentage (a bit complex?)

Tags: sql, mysql, aggregate-functions

There are a few of these around, but I am either slow tonight or I am trying to do something not possible. I have this setup

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`score` float NOT NULL,
`userId` int(11) NOT NULL
`movieId` int(11) NOT NULL
```

Taking that into account, I want to get a percentage of all the experiences from all the users in a given movie, how will I be able to do this since users can rate them as "good" with any value above 0 and as "bad" with any value below 0? Let's say a given movie has 4 experiences, where 3 are "2" and 1 is "-2" I would like to return the "porcentage" of "likeness" of that movie.

Am I crazy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
  SELECT x.movieid,
         x.score,
         COUNT(x.userid) / y.score_count  AS percentage
    FROM YOUR_TABLE x
    JOIN (SELECT t.movieid,
                 COUNT(t.score) AS score_count
            FROM YOUR_TABLE t
        GROUP BY t.movieid) y ON y.movieid = x.movieid
GROUP BY x.movieid, x.score
```

Comment: @p.campbell: MySQL's [hidden column feature](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html), returns same values as your output.

Comment: good stuff. I am still a mysql student obviously :) Curious if you think this feature is a boon or bane?

Comment: @p.campbell: I admit, I'm not proud of relying on it--my preference would be not to use it, because SQLite is the only other DB I know of that supports this.  Any others, you'll have to use your approach.

Comment: That seems to work, thanks :) I am curious where you get that "y" from though :(

Comment: @raulriera: "y" is the table alias for the derived table - it's defined on the left side of the `ON` clause.

Answer (score 1):

This should help get you started. I've used TSQL from SQL Server, but if the syntax isn't the same (it appears `CAST` should be the same in MySQL), just give it a tweak here and there will get you going in MySQL.

```
SELECT Score,
       (NumWithScore/(SELECT CAST(COUNT(userid) as decimal(10,2)) From Movies where MovieID= 7  ) * 100 
       )AS PercentageVotes
FROM 
(
     SELECT Score,           
            COUNT(*) AS NumWithScore          
     FROM  Movies AS M
     WHERE  MovieID = 7
     GROUP BY Score
) AS S
```

The data I used was:

- 2 items with value `2`
- 1 item with value `-2`

Results in:

```
Score | PercentageVotes
------+----------------
2.00  |   66.6666666
-2.0  |   33.3333333
```

[Full code up on PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/hV1rxiE5).